# Finding the minimal distance of a point from an interpolated function

Tags: interpolation, nearest

I have an interpolating parametric function (solution of a set of differential equations) and I have an external point. I would like to find the minimal distance between this point and the interpolating function.

The problem is the following

```
f[x_] := (1 - 1/x);
e = 0.884649;
a = 125.058*10^-3;
xa = 23114.528;
l = 36.525173268841186`;
ε = 0.9999796168094026`;
tfin = 7*10^6;
sol = NDSolve[{f[x[τ]] t'[τ] == ε, 
     x[τ]^2 φ'[τ] == 
      l, (x'[τ])^2 == ε^2 - 
       f[x[τ]] (1 + l^2/x[τ]^2), t[0] == 0, 
     x[0] == xa, φ[0] == Pi}, {t[τ], 
     x[τ], φ[τ]}, {τ, 0, tfin}, AccuracyGoal -> 3,
     PrecisionGoal -> 3][[1]];
pl1 = ParametricPlot[
   Evaluate[{x[τ]*Cos[φ[τ]]/10^4, 
      x[τ]*Sin[φ[τ]]/10^4} /. sol], {τ, 0, tfin}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotStyle -> Black];
pl2 = ParametricPlot[
   Evaluate[{x[τ]*Cos[φ[τ]]/10^4, -x[τ]*
       Sin[φ[τ]]/10^4} /. sol], {τ, 0, tfin}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Black];
POINT = ListPlot[{{-1.5, 0.6}}, PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[pl1, pl2, POINT, AspectRatio -> Full, PlotRange -> All]
```

This is the outcome of this code:
[image]

How can I find the minimal distance between the red point and the black curve?

Comment: Just a suggestion: `NMinimize[EuclideanDistance[]]`

Comment: @bmf thanks for your suggestion, but the problem is that I have an interpolating function, so how can I calculate this distance?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
    rgn = RegionUnion[
       Cases[pl1, Line[pts_] :> Polygon[pts], Infinity][[1]],
       Cases[pl2, Line[pts_] :> Polygon[pts], Infinity][[1]]];
    
The minimum distance to the point is given by [`RegionDistance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionDistance.html)
    
    dist = RegionDistance[rgn, {-1.5, 0.6}]
    
    (* 0.0592324 *)
    
The point in the region closest to the point is given by [`RegionNearest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionNearest.html)
    
    rgnPt = RegionNearest[rgn, {-1.5, 0.6}]
    
    (* {-1.49034, 0.541561} *)
    
Verifying the distance
    
    dist == EuclideanDistance[{-1.5, 0.6}, rgnPt]
    
    (* True *)
```

**EDIT:** minimizing the [`EuclideanDistance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EuclideanDistance.html) is much slower

```
pt[τvalue_?NumericQ] :=
 Chop[{x[τ]*Cos[ϕ[τ]]/10^4, -x[τ]*
      Sin[ϕ[τ]]/10^4} /. sol /. τ -> τvalue]

dist[τvalue_?NumericQ] := EuclideanDistance[pt[τvalue], {-1.5, 0.6}]

{minDist, arg} = NMinimize[{dist[τvalue],
   0 < τvalue < tfin}, τvalue]

(* {0.0591681, {τvalue -> 3.96287*10^6}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `DiscretizeGraphics` and `NMinimize`.

BTW,In order to avoid ambiguity, it is recommend to use `AspectRatio -> Automatic` instead of `AspectRatio -> Full`.

```
reg = DiscretizeGraphics[Show[pl1, pl2]];
pt1 = {-1.5, 0.6};
sol = NMinimize[{EuclideanDistance[pt1, {x, y}], {x, y} ∈ 
     reg}, {x, y}];
pt2 = {x, y} /. sol[[2]]
Show[Graphics[{{Red, Line[{pt1, pt2}]}}], pl1, pl2, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

> `{0.0592325, {x -> -1.49022, y -> 0.54158}}`

[image]

Comment: (+1) and just stopped by to mention that it was a nice catch your comment about the `AspectRatio` ambiguity. It's a bit odd though that `Full` gives only the point but not the distance. Nice work ;)